# how to specify session to connect to when xrdp has spawned multiple sessions?

Tags: debian, remote-desktop

I have installed xrdp on Debian 7 like so:

`apt-get install xrdp vnc4server`

I have been connecting using Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection.  I have noticed that sometimes, my existing session doesn't connected if my connection drops and I reconnect, instead I get a new connection.  My `ps` output shows this:

`vagrant@devcloud:~$ ps x | grep -i vnc
11233 ?        S      0:03 Xvnc :11 -geometry 1440x900 -depth 16 -rfbauth /home/vagrant/.vnc/sesman_vagrant_passwd -bs -ac -nolisten tcp
12404 pts/5    S      0:01 Xvnc :12 -geometry 1440x900 -depth 16 -rfbauth /home/vagrant/.vnc/sesman_vagrant_passwd -bs -ac -nolisten tcp
12855 ?        S      6:13 Xvnc :10 -geometry 1600x900 -depth 16 -rfbauth /home/vagrant/.vnc/sesman_vagrant_passwd -bs -ac -nolisten tcp`

**Question:** Is it possible to specify the session to connect to, rather than a new session being spawned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `xvncviewer`

Useage: `xvncviewer ip_address:display_no`,
where the `display_no` can be seen from the `ps` output:

`11233 ? S 0:03 Xvnc :11 -geometry 1440x900 -depth 16 -rfbauth /home/vagrant/.vnc/sesman_vagrant_passwd -bs -ac -nolisten tcp`

It then prompts for the password with which the session was created.

In ubuntu you can install it by using `sudo apt-get install xvnc4viewer` (on the client end).